# Can an object be clumsy?

Tags: word-usage

I was writing something in English when the word clumsy came to my mind to describe a French concept "inélégant". However, I use clumsy to describe an object and I am not sure it is appropriate. Here is the beginning of the sentence:

> While active tags are big and clumsy

Comment: green dreams can sleep furiously

Comment: I have no problem with "clumsy."  You might want to consider changing "big," though.  "Big" is a rather weak and imprecise adjective; I'm confident you could be more descriptive and improve the sentence at the same time.

Comment: Thank for the advice, what do you think about:"While active tags are outsized and clumsy, passive counterparts are unobtrusive and can even be built-in the object. "

Comment: General reference.

Comment: @Zonata: I think I like "oversized" better than "outsized," but, quite frankly, I don't know enough about active tags to provide a definitive answer.  How about "unnecessarily large" - might that work?

Comment: That might work, I'll go for that. Thank you again!

Comment: Even otherwise, this is not a real question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I asked the question here because I wasn't able to find the answer elsewhere... so it is not that general

Comment: @Kris Not a real question because it seems trivial to you? It is not for me and I am sure I won't be the last non native English speaker that don't know it. Perhaps I don't understand the goal of this SE named:"English language & usage"...

Comment: @Zonata: It's not General Reference because it seems trivial to me - it's because if you Google something obvious, such as quotated ["clumsy thing"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22clumsy+thing%22&oq=%22clumsy+thing%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you get tens of thousands of results. In short, it's *trivial to find out before asking here on ELU*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, I did not think about searching on Google. When I write exactly that, I do not get any answer on the first three pages of results on Google. I do have made proper researches, but no answer to the question are to be found (and even if I find one or two examples on random blog, should I take it for granted?).

Comment: @Zonata: I don't understand. The second result on my page from that search term was *"What's the most clumsy thing you've ever done fishing?"*, so clumsy is obviously okay for "non-people". If you specifically want to know about more "tangible objects", Google ["clumsy buttons"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22clumsy+buttons%22&oq=%22clumsy+buttons%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - there are thousands of them too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers From my understanding (which might be wrong, it is the reason why I am here, to learn!) "What's the most clumsy thing you've ever done fishing?" means that your actions are clumsy and so you are the clumsy one here. However, I agree I could have used the second request.

Comment: Plus there's always ["clumsy user interface"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22clumsy+user+interface%22&oq=%22clumsy+user+interface%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), or whatever specific thing you might wonder about.

Comment: You are expected to have checked **Definition of clumsy**: "difficult to handle or use; unwieldy: ***clumsy devices***; *the legal procedure is far too clumsy*" (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clumsy) / **3 (of objects)**: difficult to move or use easily; not well designed **4 (of processes)** awkward; too complicated to understand or use easily *The complaints procedure is clumsy and time-consuming.* (http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/clumsy) -- No need for further argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I think people refer to objects as "clumsy" all the time. Like, "The furniture box was big and clumsy." "COBOL is a clumsy language." Etc.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, objects can be "clumsy".  Merriam-Webster includes this definition:

> 2: awkward or inefficient in use or construction : unwieldy

Answer (score 3):

*Clumsy* is fine.  *[Cumbersome](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cumbersome)* comes to mind too.

> dialect : burdensome, troublesome